# Can't get image to appear full size with thickbox jquery

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml, thickbox

I can't seem to get my image to pop up the actual size when using thickbox. anyone know how to fix this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <title>WildFire</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/thickbox.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="body">
            <img src="images/tempbar.png">
            <div id="text">
                <img class="logo" src="images/logo.png">
                <ul class="info">
                    <li>Hours: </li>
                    <p>
                    <li> Lunch 11am - 3pm </li>
                    <li> Dinner 5pm - 10pm </li>
                    <p>
                    <li>Phone: </li>
                    <p>
                    <li>(607) 277-9143</li>
                    <p>
                    <li>Address: </li>
                    <p>
                    <li> 106 S Cayuga St </li>
                    <li>Ithaca, NY 14850 </li>
                </ul>
                <p class="linkouts">
                    <a class="thickbox" href="images/lunch.png">
                        <img src="images/lunchlink.png">
                    </a>
                <p>
                    <img src="images/dinnerlink.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            For Lounge Events Find Us On 
            <a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Ithaca-NY/WildFire-Lounge/144229581885?ref=ts" target="_blank">
                <img class ="fb" src="images/loungefb.png">
            </a>
            Come Visit
            <a href="http://www.madelines-restaurant.com/" target="_blank">
                <img class="mad" src="images/madelineslogo.png">
            </a>
            And Our Friend
            <a href="http://www.stateofithaca.com/" target="_blank">
                <img class="state" src="images/stlogo.png"
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

----------------------------css-------------------

#wrapper {
    background: #7E0000;
    height:660px;
    width:100%;
    padding:25px 0px 0px 0px;
}

#body {
    background: #000000;
    height:533px;
    width:800px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 18%;
}

#text{
    color:#ffffff;
    height:400px;
    width:400px;
    float:right;
    }

ul.info {
    margin-top:125px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

img.logo {
    float:right;
    margin:0px 30px 0px 0px;
}

.linkouts {
    color: #ffffff;
}

#footer {
    padding:55px 0px 0px 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.fb {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;  
    border: none;
}

.mad {
    margin-left:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    border: none;
}

.state {
    margin-left:20px;
    border: none;
}

/* ----- */
/* ----- >>> global settings needed for thickbox <<< ----- */
/* ----- */
*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}
/* -----*/
/* ----->>> thickbox specific link and font settings <<<-----*/
/* -----*/
#TB_window {
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
}
#TB_secondLine {
  font: 10px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color:#666666;
}
#TB_window a:link {color: #666666;}
#TB_window a:visited {color: #666666;}
#TB_window a:hover {color: #000;}
#TB_window a:active {color: #666666;}
#TB_window a:focus{color: #666666;}
/* -----*/
/* ----->>> thickbox settings <<<-----*/
/* -----*/
#TB_overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index:100;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
.TB_overlayMacFFBGHack {background: url(macFFBgHack.png) repeat;}
.TB_overlayBG {
  background-color:#000;
  filter:alpha(opacity=75);
  -moz-opacity: 0.75;
  opacity: 0.75;
}
* html #TB_overlay { /* ie6 hack */
     position: absolute;
     height: expression(document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
}
#TB_window {
  position: fixed;
  background: #ffffff;
  z-index: 102;
  color:#000000;
  display:none;
  border: 4px solid #525252;
  text-align:left;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
}
* html #TB_window { /* ie6 hack */
position: absolute;
margin-top: expression(0 - parseInt(this.offsetHeight / 2) + (TBWindowMargin = document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + 'px');
}
#TB_window img#TB_Image {

  display:block;
  margin: 15px 0 0 15px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 1px solid #666;
  border-left: 1px solid #666;
}
#TB_caption{
  height:25px;
  padding:7px 30px 10px 25px;
  float:left;
}
#TB_closeWindow{
  height:25px;
  padding:11px 25px 10px 0;
  float:right;
}
#TB_closeAjaxWindow{
  padding:7px 10px 5px 0;
  margin-bottom:1px;
  text-align:right;
  float:right;
}
#TB_ajaxWindowTitle{
  float:left;
  padding:7px 0 5px 10px;
  margin-bottom:1px;
}
#TB_title{
  background-color:#e8e8e8;
  height:27px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent{
  clear:both;
  padding:2px 15px 15px 15px;
  overflow:auto;
  text-align:left;
  line-height:1.4em;
}
#TB_ajaxContent.TB_modal{
  padding:15px;
}
#TB_ajaxContent p{
  padding:5px 0px 5px 0px;
}
#TB_load{
  position: fixed;
  display:none;
  height:13px;
  width:208px;
  z-index:103;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -6px 0 0 -104px; /* -height/2 0 0 -width/2 */
}
* html #TB_load { /* ie6 hack */
position: absolute;
margin-top: expression(0 - parseInt(this.offsetHeight / 2) + (TBWindowMargin = document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.body.scrollTop) + 'px');
}
#TB_HideSelect{
  z-index:99;
  position:fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color:#fff;
  border:none;
  filter:alpha(opacity=0);
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
* html #TB_HideSelect { /* ie6 hack */
     position: absolute;
     height: expression(document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight ? document.body.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight + 'px');
}
#TB_iframeContent{
  clear:both;
  border:none;
  margin-bottom:-1px;
  margin-top:1px;
  _margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

Comment: You may not have a choice, but just pointing out: Thickbox is deprecated and no longer supported. You can see the notice on the top of the page: http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/

Comment: Thanks, I switched over to colorbox and things seem to be going smoother.

Answer (score 0):

check the js file for thickbox. it has default values for height and width so if you don't specify them explicitly in the url (thickbox way of passing parameters) then the window appears according to the default values.

Answer (score 0):

[Shadowbox.js](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) has an option to open the as wide as the page will permit, or full size.